# CMake can't find FFMPEG in custom install path

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, cmake

I am compiling a dependency for a project on Ubuntu 10.10, and instead of having it install to /usr/local by default, I am instead installing it to /tmp/stage/usr/local.  How do I go about informing CMake of the location of this custom installed dependency when I call it to generate the build files for said project.

I am running CMake 2.8.1, and I have tried to set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH on the cmake command line, like so

```
cmake -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/tmp/stage/usr/local
```

but this doesn't seem to make a difference - the project doesn't seem to detect the dependency.

Also, if it matters, the project in question is OpenCV 2.2, and the dependency in question is FFMPEG...

Comment: I am confused by this question, are you saying that you have FFMPEG installed in /tmp/stage/usr/local and you are trying to build opencv against that FFMPEG?  Or are you trying to install something with cmake in /tmp/stage/usr/local?

Comment: FFMPEG is installed in /tmp/stage/usr/local and I am trying to build OpenCV against that FFMPEG, yes...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I figured out how to fix my problem, and trying to point CMake at the appropriate install location isn't the issue.

Apparently, CMake is unable to find the pkg-config files for FFMPEG (i.e. libavcodec.pc, libavdevice.pc, etc.) that tell it where the FFMPEG headers and libraries are located.  In a typical install scenario, these files would be located at /usr/lib/pkgconfig.  However because of the custom install location, they are instead located at /tmp/stage/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.

So that CMake could find these files, I had to add the following environment variable:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/tmp/stage/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

After which point, OpenCV built against FFMPEG as expected.

Comment: I seem to have the same problem as the original question, but I'm using CentOS 6.5. after OpenCV make fail, I see $PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable set to /usr/lib/pkgconfig and that directory contains just zlib.pc file. Is it normal? I installed ffmpeg and opencv build complains while linking opencv_perf_video, that it has undefined reference to 'avformat_network_init' which is found under ffmpeg source. I don't know where ffmpeg is installed (I tried giving prefix=/usr/local but can't find it there)

Comment: I presume that the variable was set via a bash script or manually in the terminal. Do you know, how can you set this directly from cmake? I tried set( ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/ffmpeg/build/lib/pkgconfig" ), but it somehow doesnt export the PKG_CONFIG_PATH and hence the build fails.